# Prove that for two positive arrays with equal means and equal numbers of elements, the wider the distribution, the greater the cubic sum.

Tags: proof-writing

Known conditions:
Two sets of positive number arrays A and B have the same average: (a(1) + a(2) + ... + a(N)) / N = (b(1) + b(2) + ... + b(N)) / N
The minimum value in array A is less than the minimum value in array B: min(A) < min(B)
The maximum value in array A is greater than the maximum value in array B: max(A) > max(B)

Prove that S_A is greater than S_B, where:
Sum of the cubes of array A: S_A = a(1)^3 + a(2)^3 + ... + a(N)^3
Sum of the cubes of array B: S_B = b(1)^3 + b(2)^3 + ... + b(N)^3